# How to write the output in text file from batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, text-files

I want to create one text file that has results from Java console. This needs to be done using a batch file. The below is the code for batch file I have created:

```
echo off
cls
SET CompareSize=%~1%
IF "%~1"=="" SET CompareSize=500

SET ResultFolderPath="E:\PDFCOMPARE\Results"
SET JARPath="D:\Workspace" 

REM ^^^Jar file path///

del /Q %ResultFolderPath%\S3.pdf
del %ResultFolderPath%\difference.txt
java -jar %JARPath%\PDFCompare.jar"
```

Basically, I have created a Java project that compares two pdf files and creates an output pdf file containing differences. To run the Java project, I have created one .jar file and it's being called from the batch file.

I have to run a command from this batch file that should generate a text file containing the output from Java console.

Output in cmd: [Diff-3-thread-1] INFO de.redsix.pdfcompare.DiffImage - Differences found at { page: 1, x1: 828, y1: 671}.

The same needs to be written in a text file when I run the batch file.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the last line in the script with this:

```
java -jar %JARPath%\PDFCompare.jar" > outfile.txt
```

And then the output will be written in a file called `outfile.txt`.

Comment: Don't you find the file in the directory from which you call the bat script? Try with `> %ResultFolderPath%\outfile.txt` and then you should find it in `E:\PDFCOMPARE\Results`

Comment: If I add the lines you suggested, batch file does not run.

Comment: Please be more explicit otherwise it wouldn't be possible to receive help. "does not run" or "it's not working" are are too vague wordings for someone to be able to figure out the actual problem.